# How to quickly show a linear transformation is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inverse

Assume in a normalizing flow model we have the following forward transformation given.

$$
f(z)=
\begin{bmatrix}
z_1 +2z_2\\
3z_1 + 4z_2\\
z_3 - 2z_4 \\
3z_3 -4z_4
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If a transformation is not invertible, it's easy to show, i.e., we show that the function is not bijective. Now, for this one, I am sure it's invertible and my way of "showing" it would be solving the linear system of equations to get the inverse.

My questions are:

1. Is there a sufficient condition to show a higher-dimensional function is invertible?
2. Is it sufficient to calculate the inverse here to prove $f$ has one? I have made mistakes before where I "calculated the inverse" for non-invertible functions. Technically, it worked out, but of course it was wrong.
3. Are there tools available which quickly do this for me?

Comment: You have to be careful with the domain and range when you define the inverse. For instance, while the square root looks like the inverse of squaring, $y=x^2$ is not invertible on $\mathbb R$. // Depending on how deep down the rabbit hole of isomorphisms in categories you want to go, this could be a much better question for the Math Stack than here.

Comment: The first two components depend only on $(z_1,z_2)$ and the last two only on $(z_3,z_4),$ so it's just a matter of two separate mappings $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ being invertible. And in this case that's easy because $(1,3)$ and $(3,4)$ are not scalar multiples of each other and $(1,-2)$ and $(3,-4)$ are not scalar multiples of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be looking for the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) (which actually also works perfectly well for functions that have an *explicit* inverse).  This theorem gives you sufficient conditions for the invertability of your multivariate function.  For a multivariate function with the same number of inputs and outputs, the theorem says that if the Jabocian determinant is non-zero then the function is invertible.  In the present case you have:

$$\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{z}) = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 3 & -4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad \quad \quad 
\det \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{z}) = -4 \neq 0,$$

so the function is invertible.